# Search drowdown closing on space with bootstrap accessiblity script

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

I have a search box dropdown on my site. Trouble is, when you type a search term of more than one word, it closes the dropdown since the bootstrap accessibility script thinks the user is trying to use the space to navigate. My question is twofold:

How do I keep it from tabbing out of the search box?

If I do that, is it still accessible, and if not, suggestions?

Thanks. Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/184048/

```
    <ul>
  <li class="dropdown hidden-xs"><a href="https://dev.craftonhills.edu/faculty-and-staff/index.php#" class="dropdown-toggle search-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Search</a>
    <ul class="search-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
        <div id="ctl01_Google_Custom_Search">
          <div id="search-form"> 
            <!--<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>-->
            <form action="https://www.craftonhills.edu/utilities/search.php" class="searchform" id="cse-search-box">
              <input name="cx" type="hidden" value="002089989202594896610:obysh2a6sbs">
              <input name="ie" type="hidden" value="UTF-8">
              <label for="q" class="sr-only">Search Box</label>
              <span class="gsc-input">
              <input class="search-box" id="q" name="q" onfocus="document.getElementById(&#39;q&#39;).value=&#39;&#39;" type="text" placeholder="" title="Google Custom Search" style="border: 1px solid rgb(126, 157, 185); padding: 2px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-indent: 0px;">
              </span>
              <input type="submit" class="search-button gsc-search-button" value="Go">
              <input name="siteurl" type="hidden" value="dev.craftonhills.edu/faculty-and-staff/index.php">
              <input name="ref" type="hidden" value="dev.craftonhills.edu/prospective-students/index.php">
              <input name="ss" type="hidden" value="">
              <input name="siteurl" type="hidden" value="dev.craftonhills.edu/faculty-and-staff/index.php">
              <input name="ref" type="hidden" value="dev.craftonhills.edu/prospective-students/index.php">
              <input name="ss" type="hidden" value="">
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./search_files/f.txt"></script> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i tried to reproduce with your example with Chrome on W10 but not closing the dropdown for me?

Comment: Sorry, the bootstrap accessibility add on must be included. Not sure why jsfiddle isn't keeping it... https://www.craftonhills.edu/_resources/js/bootstrap-accessibility.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this in custom jquery:

```
$('input#q').keydown(function(e) {

        // alert (e.keyCode);

    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

I think it works , but I am no pro at javascript.

B.t.w. I tested it in your sample with the js code you linked and i could type multiple words, and spaces. But I am no pro so mayybe it will conflict with something, but it is a fix :)